# xpath query filter attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

trying to filter book with id=bk112 failed.
 i am using cygwin latest and greatest. 
 appreicate anyone get this working?

file: /tmp/myLOG/xpath-filter/book.xml

```
01 xpath show all the 02 books in XML file
------------------------------------------
$  xpath /tmp/myLOG/xpath-filter/book.xml catalog/book
Found 2 nodes:
-- NODE --
<book id="bk111">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
      <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in
      detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing,
      SAX and more.</description>
</book>
-- NODE --
<book id="bk112">
      <author>Galos, Mike</author>
      <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>49.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are
      integrated into a comprehensive development
      environment.</description>
   </book>
```

### 02 xpath attribute id="bk112" and nothing found

```
$  xpath /tmp/myLOG/xpath-filter/book.xml catalog/book[@id="bk112"]
No nodes found
```

Comment: You have to state fix values in single quotation marks like `catalog/book[@id='bk112']`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe smth like this ?

```
catalog/book[contains(., "bk112")]
```